# Information about RAM management in OS Linux, protection programs

Tags: linux, security, debugging, memory-management

I'm writing a report and presentation for my college titled "Protection runtime program in RAM. Examples of work with the protected program." I'm using Linux.

I divided my report into two parts:

1. Description of technology managed RAM OS Linux - Allocated memory for applications - Protection stack for one application from other applications.
2. Protection runtime program from disassembler and debugger.

What websites, article, books about this subjects do you recommend?

Comment: Do you know about virtual memory and page protection settings?

Comment: Yes I know about virtual memory and page protection settings, but my knowledge too little. I'm need advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the following two books which describe linux memory management in detail:

- Understanding the linux kernel
- Linux device drivers